# log file creation problem in unix

Tags: unix, command-line, shell

i have command

> ccv

this will output as below

```
 Your Project : gdgdd750V64OG , Building Block : cgd9gdd .
```

if i do

> ccv | awk '{ print $9}'

```
   cgd9gdd
```

now i am tring to create a log file by running a build process

```
& tee log_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S`_`ccv | awk '{ print $9}'`
```

but this is not creating the log corrrectly.
instaed have same logs with thier name as each and every field of the output of ccv as above.that is "Your Project : gdgdd750V64OG , Building Block : cgd9gdd ."for each and every word including . , there is a file and all files are same copies.
is there anything wrong with the log file creation?

Comment: Did you try quoting?  I didn't study this too closely or try to reproduce it but that might help.

Comment: @could you please be specific?

Comment: So presumably you want a file called log_<date>_<ccv_output>.  I think you need to put everything in quotes so it would look like :
& tee "log_`date +............"

Comment: ccv expands to echo "Your Project : ${A} , Building Block : ${B}." so i used ${B} directly then i got the required result.but why is `ccv|awk '{print $9}'` is not working when i put it in the tee file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
& tee log_$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)_$(ccv | awk '{ print $9'})
```